# Buffer length etiquette

Tags: go

I have a question of etiquette. I'm implementing an RPC server, which is why this function takes a value and uses an out-variable in its parameter. This function reads from a `container/list` and fills a normal array buffer for return through the out-variable.

```
func (t *PersonalPlaylist) GetPlaylist(n int, reply *[]string) error {
    t.listMutex.Lock()

    bufLen := min(n, t.list.Len()) // mark

    buf := make([]string, bufLen) // mark
    e := t.list.Front()

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        s := e.Value.(string)
        buf[i] = fmt.Sprintf("String #%d: %s", i, s)

        e = e.Next()
        if e == nil {
            break
        }
    }

    *reply = buf

    t.listMutex.Unlock()
    return nil
}
```

[Note that this function should limit the maximum buffer size.]

Of particular note are the marked lines. I'm trying to decide whether the buffer should always be of the requested size (n) and be zero/nil-filled beyond the real data, or if the buffer should sometimes be shorter than the request value.

If the buffer is always the requested size, the code calling this function can use the value it passed as a parameter as part of the loop through the array. However, some of the values in the array may be nil, so it would have to nil check in each loop:

```
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    if reply[i] == nil {
        break; // or continue
    }
}
```

In the alternate scenario, the caller can't be sure of the buffer size, and will have to call `len(reply)` instead, but can be largely guaranteed that all the values will be non-nil.

I'm leaning towards using the function as is, and making callers unsure of the length of the buffer (while still guaranteeing a maximum possible buffer size); this is primarily because this is a relatively high level interface that will only get higher as I continue development. Is there a convention I'm not aware of that this code breaks? Or some etiquette that pushes this one way or another?

Comment: Why do you even have the `n` parameter? What does it stand for?

Comment: It's just for limiting the number of items returned. Because this is part of an RPC server, it's probably useful to limit the amount of network traffic and duplicated data in memory.

Comment: In that case I would either 1) have the user provide a preallocated []string slice and return the number of items actually written to it or 2) keep the n, allocate []string myself but return the actual valid slice, not filled with nil. The reason not to return a slice with nil at the end is simplicity and convenience. Why should the caller have to take extra steps if you know how many items there are and can easily tell it?

Answer (score 1):

Every Go programmer encounters [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). Here is an example,

```
for {
    // io.Reader
    n, err := r.Read(buf[:cap(buf)])
    buf = buf[:n]
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    // process buf
    for i := 0; i < len(buf); i++ {
        // process byte
    }
}
```

As you can see, the number of bytes actually read is returned, so we adjust the size of the buffer. We can then use `len(buf)` for the number of bytes to process.

---

Go does not have C-like null terminated strings. A Go string `s` has a length `len(s)`.

---

Not every type has a `nil` value. `nil` is only useful with pointer types. Your example doesn't appear to work.

```
var reply *[]string
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    // invalid operation: (*reply)[i] == nil (mismatched types string and nil)
    if (*reply)[i] == nil {
        break // or continue
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like when using this on non-nil-able values, it's extra important not to include extraneous "nil" values because they aren't nil, they're an actual value that might have meaning in context. This is a nuance I missed: too much Java.